# MVC Captcha ViewBag null on failed authentication (ModelState.IsValid)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to implement Captcha and i have noticed that when the modelstate evaluates to is not valid my page errors out with the message that all my viewbag.items are now null. Any idea how to fix this?

So i have a controller that sends a multiple viewbag items to my view. For example something like this:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{

...(code shortened)...
var IVariable = from i in db.SomeTable
       select i;           

foreach (var x in IVariable)
            {
                BagCategory.Add(x.ArmyCategory);
            }           
Viewbag.BagCategory = BagCategory  

}
```

The POST method looks something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[CaptchaValidation("CaptchaCode", "SampleCaptcha", "Incorrect CAPTCHA code!")]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include="ID,ItemName,Price,ArmyCategory,Race,Company,PictureLink,Notes,EmailAddress")] Sell sell)
        {
                    if (ModelState.IsValid)
                    {
                        db.ItemsOffered.Add(sell);
                        db.SaveChanges();
                        return RedirectToAction("Index");
                    }

            return View(sell);
        }
```

In my view i run through the items in viewbag.BagCategory but this is now null when captcha is failed and causes the website to explode. What can i do to fix this?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your post action you have to repopulate Viewbag.BagCategory, because now when the model isn't valid you are returning the view without the viewbag.

```
    {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    db.ItemsOffered.Add(sell);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
        ////REPOULATE THE BagCategory  HERE

        return View(sell);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! I essentially just copied the entire prepost create method into the (!modelstate.isvalid) portion and it works.

Comment: Note: there is a rejected "too radical" edit for this post: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4759325